# Is there any better way to apply custom fonts on more than one textview in android application?

Tags: android-studio, android-styles, android-fonts

Just like we can customize dimensions and color in `values` folder. Is there any way that we can do the same to fonts?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these library

[font-utils](https://github.com/mattsilber/font-utils)

[CustomFontLib](https://github.com/daniribalbert/CustomFontLib)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what if i want to create this by own, not from dependencies.